# Should [battery-charging] be merged into [batteries]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

The [battery-charging](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery-charging) tag is redundant, and I propose that it should be merged into [batteries](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batteries).

The process of charging and discharging is intrinsic to the concept of a battery, so I suggest that charging/discharging questions don't need another tag for further disambiguation. The lack of a battery-discharging tag is further evidence that we don't need the battery-charging tag.

And [battery-charging](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery-charging) has no tag wiki or excerpt written about it.

There are 17 questions currently tagged with [battery-charging](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery-charging) tag. Of those, 70% already have [batteries](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batteries). All of the [remaining questions](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery-charging+-batteries) are clearly *also* about batteries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added [battery-charging](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery-charging) to the list of synonyms for [batteries](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batteries), but haven't merged them yet.

I'll leave a bit more time for people to give feedback if they want, before I proceed with merging.